# toomanyitems mod sidebar not showing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

My too many items mod sidebar disappeared, and pressing o does not change anything. I have researched, and there was no help for me. Please help.

Comment: Have you checked your key configuration? Maybe TMI is not set to O, or there is a conflict or something.

Comment: TMI does not even show up in the controls. I even reinstalled toomanyitems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my 1.7.10 forge setup so i went to Nei instead, but to find that it was the same thing ... after some trouble shooting i found that the NEI options weren't set correctly.. I opened up the inventory and hit "o" and the options came up. after some playing around i got everything like i wanted it and was good to go. Not sure if this will work the same for the TMI mod but they do share some of the same code from my understanding so its worth a try .

Answer (score 0):

Go to \AppData\Roaming.minecraft\saves\NEI\local\world

set your NEI settings to inventory.cheatmode=2

[image: Settings]